# How to get the output of a sql count query using ibatis?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, ibatis

How can I get count of record from a particular column.

```
getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForObject(IS_EXIST_RECORD_ASSIGNMENT_TRANS_MASTER_TABLE, reportId);
```

The query I have used is as follows

```
SELECT Count(report_id) 
FROM   (SELECT report_id 
        FROM   m_assign_reports 
        UNION 
        SELECT report_id 
        FROM   m_assign_reports_trans) 
WHERE  report_id = #reportid#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resultClass declaration is mandatory. Below is the reference for the alias available for Java types 
[ALias reference for IBatis](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeAliases)